# What is adaptation data?

Tags: terminology

I came across the term, `adaptation data` when I was preparing a document. This document is about a software release. In the guide lines, it requires the description of adaptation data. So,

What is adaptation data?

What does adaptation data contain?

How can I describe the adaptation data?

Answer (score 1):

Adaptation Data are configuration data that "adapt" a program to a particular installation site or to a given set of conditions and operating environment.  Changing the max dB in an adaptation file for a car stereo firmware based on the amplication that the speakers are capable of would be an adaptation data change.  Calibrating two cameras for stereoscopic vision based on their physical configuration at a site would be adaptation data.  Changing the image filtering algorithm of a camera per environment is also adaptation.  Changing what is logged from a program per user preference is probably not adaptation data.